# Create string with action name and all user inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, action

We are reviewing our logs to make it more effective for audit analysis, therefore we are trying to include the `action` name and all inputs applied each time by the user.

Consider this sample code:

```
public JsonResult SampleActionCode(int inputA, Guid inputB, bool inputC)
    { ... }
```

So our code would be something similar to this added at that `action`:

```
string actionName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
string userInputs = inputA.ToString() + " , " + inputB.ToString() + " , " + inputC.ToString();
string userExecuted = actionName + " , " + userInputs;
//save to database
```

How could we make a general code that would cycle all inputs available and concatenate those into a string, similar to `userInputs` shown?

Comment: Perhaps you should include the detail from your other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74706244/request-querystring-with-ajax-request?noredirect=1#comment131857392_74706244

Comment: For other seeing this, the request is a POST request

Answer (score 0):

The query is stored in `Request.QueryString`, so you can iterate over its parts:

```cs
var parts = new List<string>(); // using System.Collections.Generic

foreach (var key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys) {
  parts.Add(Request.QueryString[key]);
}

string result = string.Join(", ", parts);
```

Comment: Thanks, but ```Request.QueryString.AllKeys``` is returning ```{string[0]}```. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: What's the problem? `Request.QueryString.AllKeys` returns a `string` array — [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.allkeys?view=net-7.0) is the MSDN page for property `NameValueCollection.AllKeys`. My code iterates over the keys in `Request.QueryString`, takes values, adds them into a `List<string>` and concatenates them.

Comment: When it's a single input it work as expected; but with multiple inputs it returns ```{string[0]}```. My working test case has 1x int input type. My non working test case is with int, Guid, string.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample URL you want to process?

Comment: Sure. This is the non working test case, called via ajax: ```public JsonResult CustomerEdit(Guid customer, int status, string newName, string newLocation, Guid warehouse) { ... }```

Comment: Maybe it cannot parse `Guid` or `int`. Try replacing all parameters in this method with `string`, and parsing all other types inside.

Comment: It worked when was only one ```int```. With mixed types it didn't work. With all types ```string``` it didn't work either.

Comment: Then I can only suggest checking format of the URI (in address string in your browser). Values in it should be separated with `&`.

Comment: OP Should probably include details of the jQuery/AJAX and may be mention that the request is a POST request and not a GET!

Comment: Is your non-working action method annotated with `HttpPost`?