# Request.QueryString with AJAX request

Tags: c#, ajax, request.querystring

I'm trying to join all inputs at an AJAX call to a single `string` var.

In the backend we have a `public JsonResult()` which is being called from the frontend with their arguments.

With `Request.QueryString.AllKeys` we get `{string[0]}` when it is an AJAX call. When it's a parameter in the URL it returns correctly.

Code we are using is similar to this:

```
public JsonResult CustomerEdit(Guid customer, int status, string newName, string newLocation, Guid warehouse)
{
    ...
    
    var parts = new List<string>(); // using System.Collections.Generic
    
    foreach (var key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
      parts.Add(Request.QueryString[key]);
    
    string result = string.Join(", ", parts);
}
```

Is there a way to make this work with AJAX call? Or maybe a similar way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

AJAX request is similar to:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ControllerName/CustomerEdit',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        customer: customer,
        status: status,
        newName: newName,
        newLocation: newLocation,
        warehouse: warehouse
    }),
    success: function (response) {
        },
    error: function (response) {
        }
});
```

Comment: Is it a GET or POST request from AJAX? A POST request likely won't have any query parameters. Perhaps you could show us what the request actually is to confirm

Comment: Yeah, that's a POST request and therefore the parameters will be in the body of the request not in the query string. That's why `Request.QueryString.AllKeys` appears to be empty, because it is.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if you could evaluate my original issue? It is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74678271/create-string-with-action-name-and-all-user-inputs/74678838